# Can I change AccessKey for AppName in PredictionIO?

Tags: predictionio, access-keys

I deleted my hbase folder for PredictionIO by mistake, so I lost previous AccessKey for AppName. Created new App using same name, but I need to use old AccessKey for the App for integration with clients.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Event Server Command:

```
pio accesskey
```

> Manage app access keys

[PredictionIO CLI](http://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/cli/)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

We have to use

`pio app new --access-key <<access-key>> <<app-name>>`

command.